# Aggregate in CTE between brackets to use in case after

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have this table (this is a section) that I use as a CTE for a second part of query involving aggregations and cube() functions. In the second part of query I have a case condition for count of event_id where bsp is between some range brackets.

```
╔═══════════╦════════╗
║  EVENT_ID ║ BSP    ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 3.61   ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 3.65   ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 4.00   ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 11.86  ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 20.79  ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 24.85  ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 35.83  ║
╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 146305074 ║ 155.41 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╝
```

In the second part of query I have a case condition for count of event_id where bsp is between some range brackets.

```
    CASE
                WHEN td.BSP <= 2    THEN '01-02'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 3    THEN '02-03'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 5    THEN '03-05'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 8    THEN '05-08'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 13   THEN '08-13'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 21   THEN '13-21'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 34   THEN '21-34'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 55   THEN '34-55'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 89   THEN '55-89'
                WHEN td.BSP <= 1000 THEN '89-1000'
    END
```

above are the ranges in which I have to group the BSP for each event_id
but I have to show the amount of times this happens and classify according to that. for example, with this data, my expected result would be

```
a count of 3 for BSP <=5
a count of 1 for BSP <=13
a count of 1 for BSP <=21
a count of 1 for BSP <=34
a count of 1 for BSP <=1000
```

but ion the second part I want to have a case where I can select by this amount of event_id's and give them a value based on this:

```
    CASE
        WHEN "count of event id" = 1    THEN '01'
        WHEN"count of event id" in (2,3)    THEN '02-03'
        WHEN "count of event id" >3 THEN '04-1000'
    END
        AS label
```

the complete information of query and test data is in a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dbf1a3b768e57aa5728f2bfb08a65ab&hide=3)  and just to be clear on this particular error, what should happen is that the column "Bracket label" shouldn't put all values in the bracket "04-1000" as per the select in 'Price Bracket Count' block. but should show the amount of times that an event id was in that BSP bracket.

Comment: You want just one new column? And that should tell you how many horses were in that row's bracket in that row's race?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can define the group and use `group by`:

```
SELECT v.grp, COUNT(*)
FROM td CROSS APPLY
     (values (CASE WHEN td.BSP <= 2    THEN '01-02'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 3    THEN '02-03'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 5    THEN '03-05'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 8    THEN '05-08'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 13   THEN '08-13'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 21   THEN '13-21'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 34   THEN '21-34'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 55   THEN '34-55'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 89   THEN '55-89'
                   WHEN td.BSP <= 1000 THEN '89-1000'
              END)
     ) v(grp)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(td.BSP);
```

Comment: I'm not getting where would this go, on the CTE? or on the query after?

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . This is the entire query, assuming you have a table named `td` (or with a CTE named `td`).

Comment: oh, yes, I do have a CTE called that, in the fiddle appears, I was just not getting where to put this section, I understand it, but I wasn't getting how to use it. I'll keep working with it. I don't doubt this is the solution, just struggling about how to use it :)  but this is my fault, not yours